# grails transactional service calls inside transactional controller action

Tags: grails, service, transactions, controller

What's the difference between these two controller actions:

```
  @Transactional
    def save(SomeDomain someDomain) {
        someDomain.someProperty = firstService.createAndSaveSomething(params)    //transactional
        someDomain.anotherProperty = secondService.createAndSaveSomething(params) //transactional
        someDomain.save(flush: true)
    }
```

and

```
    def save(SomeDomain someDomain) {
        combinedService.createAndSave(someDomain, params) //transactional, encapsulating first and second service calls
    }
```

My purpose is to rollback the whole save() action if a transaction fails. But not sure which one shoud I use.

Comment: Can you show us the @Transaction annotations of the two services?

Comment: Assuming all of my services have @Transactional annotation on the class level.

Comment: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/test-transactions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use both approaches.

Your listing #1 will rollback the controller transaction when `firstService` or `secondService` is throwing an exception.

In listing #2 (I expect the `createAndSave` method of `combinedService`to be annotated with `@Transactional`) will rollback the transaction if `createAndSave` throws an exception. The big plus using this approach is that this service method is theoretically reusable in other controllers.

Answer (score 0):

One of the key points about `@Transactional` is that there are two separate concepts to consider, each with it's own scope and life cycle:

1. the persistence context
2. the database transaction

The transactional annotation itself defines the scope of a single database transaction. The database transaction happens inside the scope of a persistence context. Your code:

```
@Transactional
    def save(SomeDomain someDomain) {
        someDomain.someProperty = firstService.createAndSaveSomething(params)    //transactional
        someDomain.anotherProperty = secondService.createAndSaveSomething(params) //transactional
        someDomain.save(flush: true)
    }
```

The persistence context is in JPA the EntityManager, implemented internally using an Hibernate Session (when using Hibernate as the persistence provider). Your code:

```
def save(SomeDomain someDomain) {
        combinedService.createAndSave(someDomain, params) //transactional, encapsulating first and second service calls
    }
```

**Note :** The persistence context is just a synchronizer object that tracks the state of a limited set of Java objects and makes sure that changes on those objects are eventually persisted back into the database.

**Conclusion :** The declarative transaction management mechanism (`@Transactional`) is very powerful, but it can be misused or wrongly configured easily.

Understanding how it works internally is helpful when troubleshooting situations when the mechanism is not at all working or is working in an unexpected way.

Comment: Not sure on what you're pointing about their differences. Sorry, could you clarify?

Comment: Both are maintaining hibernate session in their own way but if you want to control the way hibernate session reacts you can use @Transactional annotation otherwise use default hibernate persistence context hibernate will automatically manage it.